# mac terminal split pane vs iterm2 split pane

Tags: iterm2

I currently used iterm2 but I really miss an old OSX Terminal feature which I cannot find in iTerm2.
I'd like to create a pane mirroring the current session whithout creating a new one. In Terminal cmd+d does this.
I used this feature when I needed to easily compare console outputs obtained in current session over time

Is it possible in iterm2?

thank you